# Jenkins Pipelines: How to run one stage parallel to many?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to run one stage parallel to two stages and all this after three other stages.

Something like this (not valid syntax as-is):

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Build A') {
        }
        stage('Build B') {
        }
        stage('Build C') {
        }
        parallel {
            stages {
                stage('Build D1') {
                }
                stage('Build D2') {
                }
            }
            stage('Build D3') {
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to arrange this kind of a structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do that are [sequential stages in parallel](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/).

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage("build and deploy on Windows and Linux") {
            parallel {
                stage("windows") {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    stages {
                        stage("build") {
                            steps {
                                bat "run-build.bat"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("deploy") {
                            when {
                                branch "master"
                            }
                            steps {
                                bat "run-deploy.bat"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                stage("linux") {
                    agent {
                        label "linux"
                    }
                    stages {
                        stage("build") {
                            steps {
                                sh "./run-build.sh"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("deploy") {
                             when {
                                 branch "master"
                             }
                             steps {
                                sh "./run-deploy.sh"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```